# Set up wordpress in local MAMP server

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost, mamp

[image]

I am getting this error while establishing wordpress on local mamp, when i put the credentials as Database name - wordpress, user - root, password- root, table prefix - wp and host - local host

my every credential is fine but still getting the error as shown in pitcure

Answer (score 0):

Open *wp-config.php* file and check the following values

```
define( 'DB_NAME', "Enter Database Name Here" );
define( 'DB_USER', "Enter Database Username Here" );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', "Enter Database Password Here" );
```

In the above code enter your details correctly without any spaces. If still not able to connect

change

```
define( 'DB_HOST', "localhost" );
```

to

```
define( 'DB_HOST', "127.0.0.1" );
```

and try to connect once again.

If not check MySQL on which port it is running